# ASIHTTPRequest multiple Async request issue

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

When I put an asynchronous ASIHTTPRequest to work, called Request1, when it finishes it calls the `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request2` which is the wrong thread. How does that happen, and more importantly, how do i avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASIHTTPRequest` should always call it's request finished / error methods on the main thread.

If you want to then go back into another thread then it's up to you to do that (i.e. `performSelectorInBackground:`, `NSOperationQueue` etc).

Comment: I hoped i didnt have to go into queues :(.. I just want 2 operations, one for downloading a file, and another for posting some data.

Comment: You shouldn't have to - if you do the download and then the post of some data both using ASIHTTPRequest's startAsyncronous then it will always work in the background, only dipping into the main thread for the callbacks.

Comment: That's what I do, but I want to check requestFinished for the async upload thread, and present an alert when it's finished. But when the download request calls the same requestfinished as the upload request.

Comment: Ah, take a look at the docs - you can pass a custom selector for each request i.e. `[uploadRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadComplete:)];` (you can also set custom did fail selectors). http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_success_and_failure_for_multiple_requests

Comment: Oh thanks alot! This was my original question. Upvoted and answered :)